# A question after a javaweb project is started

Tags: windows, intellij-idea, networking, firewall, java-web-start

When I start the project, the browser did not open "http://localhost:8080/page.do? operate=page&page=login" and waits until a 404 error is reported. tomcat appears to start normally.

[picture description 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SsO89.png)

[picture description 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xGpR3.png)

[picture description 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z6e9r.jpg)

Actually, everything was fine yesterday until this morning when I did something with telnet and changed some Settings in windows. I've got all the Settings right here, but it's not working.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.